# Browser complaining about SSL certificate when send request to a subdomain

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vercel, next.js14

I've deployed a newly created Next.js app on Vercel & it all works great when I request homepage at `https://new-cms-yyjf.vercel.app/`
but once I add a subdomain to the url like `https://jhon.new-cms-yyjf.vercel.app/`, I get an error from browser about SSL certificate:

> An error occurred during a connection to wailsson.new-cms-yyjf.vercel.app. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Knowing that my app has logic code to receive subdomains and redirect and render pages based on subdomain.

It is my first time on Vercel and I am still reading docs.

Answer (score 0):

While the domain `jhon.new-cms-yyjf.vercel.app` does resolve to Vercel's infrastructure, Vercel only possesses a wildcard SSL certificate for their `vercel.app` subdomain:

[image]

As shown in the screenshot, Vercel serves an SSL certificate for `*.vercel.app`. A wildcard SSL certificate can only match a one-level deep subdomain (for instance, `*.example.net` will match `sub.example.net` but not `sub.sub.example.net`), per [RFC2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1):

> Matching is performed using the matching rules specified by [RFC2459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2459). If more than one identity of a given type is present in the certificate (e.g., more than one dNSName name, a match in any one of the set is considered acceptable.) Names may contain the wildcard character * which is considered to match any single domain name component or component fragment. E.g., *.a.example matches foo.a.example but not bar.foo.a.example. f*.example matches foo.example but not bar.example.

Therefore, when a request is made to `jhon.new-cms-yyjf.vercel.app`, Vercel's infrastructure doesn't have a suitable SSL certificate to serve, leading to the SSL error.